# How do I call map() on an IntStream and return a different type?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to do this:

```
            IntStream.range(0, fileNames.size())
                .map(i -> "mvn deploy:deploy-file" +
                        " -DrepositoryId=" + REPO_ID +
                        " -Durl=" + REPO_URL +
                        " -Dfile=" + LIBS + fileNames.get(i) +
                        " -DgroupId=" + GROUP_ID +
                        " -DartifactId=" + artifactName.get(i) +
                        " -Dversion=" + versionNumbers.get(i) +
                        " -DgeneratePom=true;")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this doesn't compile because `map()` passes in an `int` and returns an `int`.  How do I map from `int` to `String`?

PS: Is there a more idiomatic way to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IntStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) has a `mapToObj` method for this.  With its generics, no need to cast, either:

```
        IntStream.range(0, fileNames.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> "mvn deploy:deploy-file" +
                        " -DrepositoryId=" + REPO_ID +
                        " -Durl=" + REPO_URL +
                        " -Dfile=" + LIBS + fileNames.get(i) +
                        " -DgroupId=" + GROUP_ID +
                        " -DartifactId=" + artifactName.get(i) +
                        " -Dversion=" + versionNumbers.get(i) +
                        " -DgeneratePom=true")
                .map(s -> s + ";")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```